# Proof of NOT initialization of weights to zero

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Can anyone provide me the mathematical details to why we shouldn't initialize a neural network (single layer ANN) weights to zero? In multi-layer we don't initialize it to zero because of loss of symmetry but why can't we initialize a single layer network weights to zero ?

Comment: Papers like https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03425 shows that weight initialization to zero could lead to better results.

Comment: Single layer meaning single hidden layer? Or single layer meaning logistic regression?

Comment: @JanKukacka single hidden layer or may be a dense single layer at the output of a model.